# TestNG Mark a Test as Failed if a Particular Path is Used

Tags: java

Is there a way to mark a test as failed in the TestNG framework if a certain path is followed?

I know I can use system.exit(1); or something similar to mark an abnormal termination but it doesn't seem to actually mark the test as failed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
org.testng.Assert.fail("you wandered onto the wrong path");
```

Comment: this did not click on my mind

Comment: Two roads diverge in a wood... and I, I `Assert.fail`ed...

Comment: I used it, It help me to fail test case in result but also getting **org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94) 
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:101) 
at Testcases.SignUpTest.Company_Invalid_Check(SignUpTest.java:277) 
34 lines not shown** , Can you please tell me how can I avoid it?

Comment: Helping Hands, please create a new question for that.  In the question, include your stack trace and the corresponding code fragment.  It may also help to summarize what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can always throw exception -

```
if("this path is followed") {
throw new Exception("was bound to fail!!!")
}
```

Comment: An exception does not seem to fail a test either. I might just put in some code which could never be executed. In my situation this is using some robot code inside of a webdriver test.

Comment: Are you handling exception in your test?

Comment: Throwing `AssertionError` instead of `Exception` (which is what `Assert.fail()` does under the covers) would be better and would prevent the error from being swallowed by a `catch (Exception)` block. Of course, `catch (Exception)` is generally a bad idea anyways...